What are the differences between StreamExt from the tokio_stream and futures crates?
While developing my web application, I used the then method from tokio_stream::StreamExt to manage the request stream. Surprisingly, I observed that when replacing tokio_stream::StreamExt with futures::StreamExt my code still worked.
I'm curious about the underlying reason for this. I attempted to consult the documentation at docs.rs/tokio_stream; however, I found it to be quite challenging to comprehend. Could someone lend me a hand in understanding this matter?

What version of tokio_util are you referring to? I don't see any StreamExt here https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/index.html

There's a tokio_stream::StreamExt trait, is that the one you mean?

They are different traits that offer identical adapters for common stream operations (map, filter, collect, etc.). So if you are only using basic things, you probably won't notice a difference.
You should generally prefer the one from the futures crate, since it provides more methods (i.e. more functionality). However, tokio-stream's version has a few tokio-specific methods related to time (throttle, timeout, etc.).

For some history: way back in tokio 0.1 days, they had a StreamExt trait based on futures' Stream (see tokio::prelude at the time) that only had tokio-specific methods, not general purpose ones. However, over time the futures' crate got their own StreamExt trait that housed the adapter methods while Stream itself was stripped to only the bare functionality (see futures 0.1 -> 0.3). So in tokio 0.2, StreamExt was kept around since it had tokio-specific methods (see tokio::stream at the time) but it copied the generalized methods to keep existing code working.
Finally in tokio 1.0, the stream functionality was completely removed to a separate crate, tokio-stream, (see tokio::stream now) because they didn't want to stabilize it with a Stream trait that wasn't from the standard library. For more context, the intentions were that futures' Stream trait was going to be subsumed into the standard library, but that thus far has not happened.

While merging future's Stream into std has not happened yet, it is definitely still planned, will it be called AsyncIterator (as already exists) or Stream.
